# Google Map Integration in OS X Application

Tags: objective-c, macos, google-maps, webview

I would like to use use Google Map in my MAC application.

I found the iOS SDK of Google Maps but not for OS X.

I want to show two annotation and a line connecting them on Google Map. Coordinate of both annotation are dynamic as per user selection.

Below is the way I find out that can work:

- Call a API and pass the location coordinate for both annotation.
- Now Server side a html form is generate using javascript and create a page which is showing the 2 annotation and line connecting them.
- In Api Response I will get the URL of that html page.
- I will show this page in `UIWebView`.

I want to know is there any other way I can achieve this.

I want to distribute application outside the mac app store and to distribute outside mac store I need to sign app with Developer ID which does not support the MAPs.

I didn't find anything related to this that's why I created this thread.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ported the [Mapbox iOS SDK](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/) over to OS X. It has a lot of the features of MapKit, but it’s open source and should also work in a developer-signed application such as yours. To use the Mapbox OS X SDK, download the latest release from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/) (look for releases beginning with “osx-”) and follow the instructions in README.md. An API reference is included.

> I want to show two annotation and a line connecting them on Google Map. Coordinate of both annotation are dynamic as per user selection.

To display the annotations on-screen, you’ll need the MGLPointAnnotation and MGLPolyline classes. You can move the point annotations dynamically by setting their `coordinate` properties. The polyline, however, is immutable; to change its path, remove the existing polyline and add a new one with the new coordinates.

Comment: Found it here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/osx

Comment: However, how can this be adapted to display Google Maps tiles rather than Mapbox tiles?

Comment: @gpdawson Using Google Maps tiles through a non-Google library, such as the Mapbox OS X SDK or MapKit, would violate the [Google Maps terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions). It may technically be possible with their raster tiles, but the experience would be poorer than a vector map. Since Google doesn’t provide any native libraries for the Mac, I’d encourage you to try out the Mapbox SDK ([latest version](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/releases/tag/osx-v0.1.0)) with Mapbox tiles, [which you can customize](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/).

Comment: OK Understood. I think Mapbox is a very nice mapping implementation.  However, for my purposes I need highest-res satellite imagery available, which seems still to be from Google. (And this Q was originally about Google maps too of course.) So for now I'm intending to license via Google and using https://github.com/Oomph/MacMapKit - it's very out of date code and lots of problems to resolve but it's the best starting point I can find.

Comment: FYI it’s called the [Mapbox macOS SDK](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/macos) now. Hopefully that’s the last name change for awhile. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make it with WebKit and the Google Maps API.

MapKit is available in OS X 10.9 Mavericks: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/index.html

There are of course many ways of hiding the fact that you're using WebKit but if they violate Apple's or Google's TOS then submission to the App Store won't be possible.

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: I can not use MapKit as it's not supported with developer id signed application

Comment: Hello, have you tried Google Map plugin which detects OS X? Would that be helpful and is it supported with developer id ?

Comment: I don't have much idea about that can you give me more details or any usefull links for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but as far as i read should help you for the integration. Take a look at this: http://download.cnet.com/Google-Maps-Plugin/3000-2074_4-70778.html

Comment: I guess it's application it can not be integrated like sdk